# Recommend a book on Bayesian Hierarchical Modeling

Tags: references, hierarchical-bayesian

I would like to learn about Bayesian Hierarchical Modeling and its applications to time series analysis. I would appreciate a good book / publication / course which will both teach some fundamental underlying theory and give hands on procedures to set up the models and actually perform the inference.

I want to model a certain complex process. I observe behavior of a large amount of individuals. I have a likelihood model of how individual behavior depends on some hidden variables. However, these hidden variables are individual, change slowly over time, and also depend on specific personal properties such as age and sex. The goal of this study is to infer the values of hidden variables for each participant as a function of time, as well as the associated uncertainties.

Comment: BDA, the BUGS book, Hoff's A First Course in Bayesian Statistical Methods, Lee's Bayesian Statistics: An Introduction, The Bayesian Choice [my book] all have hierarchical chapters.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks a lot